# Need help to solve limits question (differential calculus)

Tags: calculus, limits

Please help to solve the following:

Identify the first incorrect step in the following “Proof”, and explain why it’s incorrect. Provide and example for the case:
If  lim x->z f(x)g(x) = A,  then there are numbers  B and C  such as:
lim x->z f(x) = B
lim x->z g(x) = C
And then A = BC

Proof: If  lim x->z f(x)g(x) = A , then:

lim x->z f(x)g(x) =  (lim x->z f(x)) ( lim x->z g(x))                               (step1)
Let B the value of lim x->z f(x)   and C the value of  lim x->z g(x) :
lim x->z f(x) = B
lim x->z g(x) = C
From the theorem of limit multiplication follows that  A = BC

Comment: Step 1  is wrong. It assumes existence of the limits on the right.

Comment: It is true that if the limit of f(x) and g(x) are defined as x approaches a, then then the limit of the product equals the product of the limit.  However, there are cases where the limits of f(x) or g(x) are not defined but the limit fg(x) is.  Now find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$f(x)=x$$ and $$g(x)=\frac {1}{x}$$ Thus $$f(x)g(x)=1$$

Then $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)g(x)= 1=A $$
But g(x) does not have a limit at $x=0$ so $A=BC$ is not happening.